# Reset UIImageView Pinch and Rotate Gesture property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

**Step : 1** `// Add Gestures`

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationGestureDetected:)];

UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

        if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            CGFloat rotation = [recognizer rotation];
            [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, rotation)];
            [recognizer setRotation:0];
        }
```

**Step : 2**

Rotate and Zoom Image.

**Step : 3**

```
//Change Image
self.tempImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“demo_%d” , 0 ]];
```

Result: Image is Stretched

[image]

Comment: How to explain your problem after posting a new topic?

Comment: Can you show us some code?